# CSS Flexbox - make elements containing other elements same height

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a layout using Flexbox where I have elements which consist of 3 other internal elements. The parent `item` element contains 3 `divs`: `image`, `button`, `text`. The issue is that my items will not always contain images or text that is the same height as the others. The button is the one thing that will have a consistent height. I am trying to figure out if it's possible to have each of my `image` divs be the same height as the tallest one and same for the `text` divs. I would also like the images to be vertically aligned to the bottom, so if one element has a shorter image, the white space to make the element the same height will go above the image like this:

[image]

And here is what I have so far:

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content:center;
}

.item {
    max-width:200px;
    margin:0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x270" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that I could do this using Javascript to loop through each item to get the tallest and change the CSS of all others, but I'd like to use only CSS if possible. I also know that I could just set the height of the image container to the height of the tallest image, but these images are going to be dynamic and there are going to be a lot of them, so I'd rather have a solution that doesn't require hardcoding values.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get the images to align as well as the text to all be the same height using straight flex properties, or even css. To get the content to align along the bottom checkout the align-items property though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexing the `.item` class and adding `justify-content: flex-end;` would provide the majority of the affect, but as far as I know you'd have to set a specific height on at least one of the items if you want two elements to be aligned the same across flexbox. Happy to be proven wrong though.

You could alternatively use `margin-top: auto` on the first child to push any unused space to the top and everything else down.

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content:center;
}

.item {
    max-width:200px;
    margin:0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text {
    height: 36px; /* magic number */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x270" />
    </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>Click Me</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Totally welcome. Would be interesting to hear if you improve upon this.